# Using a hypercard file on a Windows machine

Tags: windows, macos, emulation

my parents were cleaning out their house and found an old Mac Classic which I used a long time ago to run [HyperCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperCard). I made a couple things which I'd like to keep but I don't know what appliations will even run Hypercard files anymore. Also, I'm using a Windows computer now. Can anyone recommend an emulator or some way to convert it to something I can use on my Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a 68k Macintosh emulator:
http://basilisk.cebix.net/

Here's a link to HyperCard:
http://www.macintoshgarden.org/apps/hypercard-241

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [Revolution](http://www.runrev.com/) can import HyperCard stacks. A commercial application, [DIFfersifier](http://economy-x-talk.com/differsifier.html), can export text data from HyperCard stacks to files that can be read by database applications:

> DIFfersifier is a simple conversion
>   utility that exports text data from
>   HyperCard, Revolution and MetaCard
>   stacks to files that can be read by
>   most database applications.
>
> DIFfersifier 3.4 runs under Mac OS X
>   and Windows. It has not been tested
>   with earlier MacOS versions. If you
>   are using a Macintosh, AppleScript 1.1
>   or later has to be installed.
>   AppleScript enables a small number of
>   additional features, which are only
>   available for MacOS.

Revolution has a free version (revMedia), and DIFfersifier can be purchased for as little as 14.95 euro for a private license.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [TileStack.com](http://tilestack.com/). They've got a web-based HyperCard "emulator" that has been able to play a few of my own stacks. Pretty slick.